# Nginx with rtmp module and ffmpeg adaptive stream is not creating master dash manifest

Tags: nginx, video-streaming, ffmpeg, rtmp

I have a working setup of nginx with the rtmp module working like a charm creating live streams with both dash and hsl. No problem so far.

When I try to enable ffmpeg transcoding for adaptive streaming, it creates the hls version just fine, the video chunks, a m3pu8 for each video version and a master m3u8 that is the one I call from the web player.

But in the dash version I get the chunks, the mpd manifest for each version but no master manifest.

Am I missing something? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

nginx.conf:

```
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}
rtmp { 
    server { 
        listen 1935; 

        application live { 
            live on; 
            exec ffmpeg -i rtmp://stream.server.net/live/$name -threads 1
            -c:v libx264 -profile:v baseline -b:v 768K -s 640x360 -f flv -c:a aac -ac 1 -strict -2 -b:a 96k 
            rtmp://stream.server.net/liveout/$name_360 
            -c:v libx264 -profile:v baseline -b:v 1024K -s 852x480 -f flv -c:a aac -ac 1 -strict -2 -b:a 128k rtmp://stream.server.net/liveout/$name_480;
        } 

        application liveout {
                live on;
                hls on;
                hls_path /home/stream/hls/;
                hls_fragment 4s;
                hls_playlist_length 60s;

                dash on;
                dash_path /home/stream/dash;
                dash_fragment 10s;
                dash_playlist_length 30s;
                dash_nested off;

                hls_variant _360 BANDWIDTH=448000;
                hls_variant _480 BANDWIDTH=1152000;
        }



    } 
} 
 
http { 
    server {
        server_name stream.server.net;
        root /home/stream/;


        location /hls {
            # Serve HLS fragments
            types {
                application/vnd.apple.mpegurl m3u8;
                video/mp2t ts;
            }
            root /home/stream/;
            add_header Cache-Control no-cache;

            # CORS setup
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length';

            # Allow CORS preflight requests
            if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
                add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
                add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
                return 204;
            }
        }


        location /dash { 
            root /home/stream/; 
            # Serve DASH fragments
            types {
                application/dash+xml mpd;
                video/mp4 mp4;
            }

            add_header Cache-Control no-cache;

            # CORS setup
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length';

            # Allow CORS preflight requests
            if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
                add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
                add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
                return 204;
            }        
        }


        location /stat {
            rtmp_stat all;
            # Use this stylesheet to view XML as web page
            # in browser
            rtmp_stat_stylesheet stat.xsl;
        }

        location /stat.xsl {
            # XML stylesheet to view RTMP stats.
            # Copy stat.xsl wherever you want
            # and put the full directory path here
            root /home/stream/;
        }



 
    
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/stream.server.net/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/stream.server.net/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
 
    types {
        text/html html;
        application/dash+xml mpd;
    } 
 
    server {
    if ($host = stream.server.net) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

 
        listen 80;
        server_name stream.server.net;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}}
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the missing feature of dash_variant in [nginx-rtmp-module](https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module). It seems like [ut0mt8](https://github.com/ut0mt8/nginx-rtmp-module) has added this feature but it may not be stable.